# Design tables which can store different values and respective indicators

Tags: mysql, database

Hi I need help on designing database table for the following rules :

There is a need of a storage of data for the weather of each day.It needs to store either 1 or 2 values of weather as defined by the system.

The following parameter needs to be applied while designing the table.

- If the weather is above 100 Fahrenheit we need to store the value and
  a column indicating the weather is above threshold
- If the weather is below 20 Fahrenheit we need to store the value and
  a column indicating the weather is below threshold
- If the weather is above 40 Fahrenheit and below 80 Fahrenheit we need
  to store the value and a column indicating the weather is in-range
- If the weather is below 40 Fahrenheit and above 80 Fahrenheit we need
  to store the value and a column indicating the weather is not in
  range

Thanks in advance.

Comment: so you want to input the weather column (temp) and the database should calculate the wether2 column (above threshold/in-range etc?)

Comment: Will you be using it with a backend programming language such as PHP ? If you are the you can apply backend logic and only save temperature value (ex 100 Fahrenheit) and then check conditions using if else and display message  (such as above threshold ).

Comment: I would suggest that you dont store this extra column. Instead when you want to select row within one of these groups apply these criteria to your search criteria, or create 4 views that do this. Then if the criteria change all you need to do is amend SQL search criteria and not perform some complex mods to the database

Comment: Your 4th point: How can temp be below 40 and above 80 Fahrenheit ?

Comment: @ZahiroMor: We can think of this as static entry but for different countries.Different country will set these parameters differently.

Comment: Just store the temperature.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using MySQL 5.7 you could use GENERATED COLUMNS:

```
create table wheather (
  temp int,
  hot  int generated always as (if(temp>30,1,0)) virtual,
  cold int generated always as (if(temp<20,1,0)) virtual
);

insert into wheather (temp) values (10), (20), (30), (40);
select * from wheather;
```

Gives:

```
temp    hot    cold
-------------------
10      0      1
20      0      0
30      0      0
40      1      0
```

If using earlier versions of MySQL, like 5.5, use a view that does the same.

---

**Update:** From the comments I learned that the thresholds vary for different locations.
Given that, I suggest a second table that holds the thresholds for each location and then 
join the two tables:

```
create table wheather (
    location char(20),
    temp     int
);

insert into wheather (location, temp) values 
    ('Florida', 10), ('Florida', 20), ('Florida', 30), ('Florida', 40),
    ('Alaska', 10),  ('Alaska', 20),  ('Alaska', 30),  ('Alaska', 40);

create table thresholds (
    location        char(20),
    low             int,
    high            int,
    inrange_lower   int,
    inrange_upper   int,
    outrange_lower  int,
    outrange_upper  int
);

insert into thresholds values 
    ('Florida', 30, 60, 35, 45, 20, 50),        
    ('Alaska',  10, 30, 15, 25,  5, 40);

select w.location,
       w.temp, 
       if(w.temp < t.low,'yes','no') as cold,
       if(w.temp > t.high,'yes','no') as hot,
       if(w.temp between t.inrange_lower and t.inrange_upper,'yes','no') as in_range,
       if(w.temp < t.outrange_lower or w.temp > t.outrange_upper,'yes','no') as out_of_range
  from wheather w left join thresholds t on w.location=t.location;
```

Gives:

```
+----------+------+------+-----+----------+--------------+
| location | temp | cold | hot | in_range | out_of_range |
+----------+------+------+-----+----------+--------------+
| Florida  |   10 | yes  | no  | no       | yes          |
| Florida  |   20 | yes  | no  | no       | no           |
| Florida  |   30 | no   | no  | no       | no           |
| Florida  |   40 | no   | no  | yes      | no           |
| Alaska   |   10 | no   | no  | no       | no           |
| Alaska   |   20 | no   | no  | yes      | no           |
| Alaska   |   30 | no   | no  | no       | no           |
| Alaska   |   40 | no   | yes | no       | no           |
+----------+------+------+-----+----------+--------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

The code works, but is simplified, i.e. it lacks PKs, INDEXEs, FK constraints, and a DATE column.
And I may have gotten the actual values and/or comparisons wrong, but it may point you to a direction.

Of course you can create a view for the SELECT statement. If you really want to *store* the values, then I suggest four extra columns in the WHEATHER table (cold/hot/in_range/out_of_range) and populate them with an INSERT trigger with the values from the THRESHOLD table. This way you can change the thresholds (in THRESHOLDS) later without changing the values in WHEATHER. For example, if you'd created your database 50 years ago, then 50 °F would be considered *hot* whereas meanwhile 55 °F is hot (due to climate change). It depends on your use case. The view gives "life updates", the trigger gives "historical values".

Comment: The OP wants to specifically store 4 different values specified.

Comment: @Golden_flash True, and my thresholds are also not his. I just wanted to show a possible solution, not write the complete DDL for him.

Comment: @Golden_flash: Yes you are correct.I want to store this values.Say for a country X - the values might be 100 F(Above Threshold),20 F(Below Threshold),(40F-80F) in range,(40-90)range out values.For country Y the values will be different.However we need to store the values and indicator for the same

Comment: @PerlDog: Thank you for the answer.However how do I go ahead and store the range values and its respective indicator.

Comment: Ahh, I misunderstood that. So e.g. 50 °F in Florida is _cold_ but in Alaska the same is considered _hot_. Hmmm. I'll think about it.

Comment: @PerlDog: Thank you .This really helps me.

Comment: @Amz If it really helped you, you could consider _accepting_ the answer. I'd appreciate that. :-)